# Vuestic UI date input not working on MacOS Safari

Tags: vue.js, safari, vuejs3, vuestic

I am using Vuestic's **va-date-input** in my Vue 3 project. It's working fine in chrome but when a user clicks the date picker in safari browser (v16.5) it gets freezes(user has to reload the page) and there's an error in console

> [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of mounted hook (screenshot attached below)

I have tried multiple things. Like using it without v-model and formatting attribute. But nothing seems to be working.

Here's I am using it.

```
<va-date-input
            v-model="startDate"
            :key="startDate"
            :format="backendDateFormat"
            color="#53389E"
            placement="bottom"
          />
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same issue on https://ui.vuestic.dev/ui-elements/date-input? I'm not seeing any problems in Safari 16.3. You may need to update both vuestic-ui and vue to the latest versions.

Also, make sure your `backendDateFormat` function works correctly in Safari.